# How can I automatically deallocate an Azure instance once a script is complete?

Tags: azure, cloud

I want to spin up an Azure Linux instance, process some data and then have the instance automatically enter the stopped (deallocated) state to avoid further billing.

Is it possible to do this, ideally by simply running a command on the instance after the job is complete?

Edit: after the comments below helped with searching for the relevant command, I have tried running the following on the instance, but with an error:

```
[server]$ az vm deallocate --resource-group MyResources --name VMName
```

which results in the error

```
getattr(): attribute name must be string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/cli/main.py", line 36, in main
    cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/cli/core/application.py", line 177, in execute
    self.configuration.load_params(command)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/cli/core/application.py", line 50, in load_params
    commands.load_params(command)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 408, in load_params
    import_module(module_to_load).load_params(command)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/vm/__init__.py", line 10, in load_params
    import azure.cli.command_modules.vm._params  # pylint: disable=redefined-outer-name, unused-variable
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/vm/_params.py", line 78, in <module>
    c.register_cli_argument('vm', 'zone', zone_type)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 62, in register_cli_argument
    if (isinstance(is_supported, tuple) and getattr(is_supported, self._operation_group)) or is_supported:
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

Answer (score 1):

De-allocating the instance requires running the command against the Azure API to have it shutdown the VM, if you have Windows shutdown then it will not de-allocate. What you could do is install the Azure PowerShell cmdlets on your VM, then have the end of your script call the stop-azurermvm command to shut itself down.

That said, have you also considered looking at Azure Functions? This would do all this work for you/

Comment: I forgot to specify in the question, I was planning on using a Linux instance. I assume PowerShell commands won't work?

Comment: Well you could use PowerShell core, but also you could use the Azure CLI and bash scripts.

Comment: @SamCogan Azure CLI has Managed Service Identity support when running in a VM which means you don't have to store a password or certificate on the VM to authenticate with Azure to stop the VM. I prefer this.

Comment: @GregGalloway yes, good point

Comment: Can either of you provide any code examples? That's what I'm looking for!

Comment: I've edited the original question to reflect what I've found so far